# jQuery: hide by class name and then show next element by the same class name?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create a demonstration type of thing in my page.

basically the first element is showing on the page load and the rest are hidden.

once the close button inside the element has been clicked, I need this showing element to hide and the next element with the same class name to show and the same process until there is no more element in the `next()` to show.

my html looks like this:

```
<a class="tooltip" href="#">
<div style="left:-200px;" class="bubs"><div style=" position:absolute; top:10px; right:10px;"><i class="cls" aria-hidden="true"></i></div></div>

<span class="tooltiptext">Some texts</span><i style="color:#F90;" class="fa fa-thumbs-up" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>



<a class="tooltip" href="#">
<div style="left:-200px;" class="bubs"><div style=" position:absolute; top:10px; right:10px;"><i class="cls" aria-hidden="true"></i></div></div>

<span class="tooltiptext">Some texts</span><i style="color:#F90;" class="fa fa-thumbs-up" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
```

And my jquery looks like this:

```
$('.cls').click(function() {
    $('.bubs').hide();
     $(".bubs").next().show();
});
```

My simple code will hide `.bubs` that is showing but it doesn't show the next `.bubs`

Could someone please advise on this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Open your browser console. Run the code " $('.bubs').hide();" then run "$(".bubs").next()" if you are selecting the element you intend to show, then make the call $(".bubs").next().show();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.bubs` are not siblings. Go to ancestor `a` and then find `.bubs` in next `a` like following.

```
$('.cls').click(function () {
    $(this).closest('.bubs').hide();
    $(this).closest('a').next('a').find('.bubs').show();
});
```

Comment: unfortunately that didn't work. hides the first element but doesn't show the next element.

Comment: ah, check the double $$

Answer (score 1):

The JQuery method "next" should contain the class of the next element you want to show.It should work if you use next(".bubs") like this :

```
$('.cls').click(function() {
$('.bubs:first').hide();
 $(".bubs:first").next(".bubs").show();
});
```

**Note :** I assume that the element you want to hide is the first one who has "bubs" class.

Comment: What about this : $('.cls').click(function() {
$('.bubs:first').hide();
 $(".bubs:first").closest(".bubs").show();
});

Comment: the Jackson's code worked. thanks for the help though.